# Handler is keeping activity from finishing

Tags: android, android-activity, handler

I have declared private Handler mHandler = new Handler(); and used this handler many times in my activity. For example:

```
        // fade out view nicely after 5 seconds
        mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                tview.setText(null);
            }
        }, 4000);
```

or

```
mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
public void run() {
    tview.setText(null);
    parentLayout.findViewById(R.id.fireplace).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    parentLayout.removeView(findViewById(R.id.fireplace));
    water_room.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    playSound(fountainSoundID); 
}
}, 3000);
```

Now, if I go back (via pressing back button) when this handler has already started it's action, because of this handler activity is not finishing.I want mHandler stop whatever it is doing and not keep the activity from finishing. How do I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How do I do that?

I'm little confused what are you trying to say but if i understood it correctly, you need to override [onBackPressed()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onBackPressed%28%29) method and here you'll stop Handler and finish Activity.

**Pseudo-code:**

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
   // stop Handler
   handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
   // to stop anonymous runnable use handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
   finish();
}
```

Since your *Runnable* is anonymous you need to use second approach:

```
handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
```

If you're confused from this method, here is its doc:

> Remove any pending posts of callbacks and sent messages whose obj is
>   token. If token is null, all callbacks and messages will be removed.

Comment: @Nazerke Loot at answer. So your runnable is anonymous so you need to use commented code.

Comment: I do not have pointer to the Runnable, as you can see from my code.
        mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                tview.setText(null);
            }
        }, 4000);

I declare Runnable as a method parameter

Comment: @Nazerke yes how i said, look at answer carefully and read also comments.

Comment: Thank you. Sorry, I didn't notice the update you made in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Get pointer of the `Runnable` and try following:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    myHandler.removeCallbacks(myRunnable);
    finish();
}
```